# How to extract string from pdf in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm a newbie in rust and I'm trying to use the [pdf_extract](https://docs.rs/pdf-extract/0.6.2/pdf_extract/) package to handle pdfs. I would like to extract the string from the pdf. I saw that the function for this is defined like this:

```rust
pub fn extract_text<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<String, OutputError>
```

So I used `extract` to manage the error:

```rust
use pdf_extract::extract_text;

fn main() {
    let text = extract_text("file.pdf").expect("Unable to read file");
    println!("{}", &text)
}
```

This, however, returns an error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempted to leave type `linked_hash_map::Node<std::vec::Vec<u8>, object::Object>` uninitialized, which is invalid', /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/core/src/mem/mod.rs:671:9
```

Since the error message is different from the one I used in `expect`, I don't know what the error means. It seems to me that the command `let text=extract_text("meu.pdf").expect("Unable to read file");` worked, but it still gave an error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this is a bug from the crate you used

Comment: To be precise - this is an incorrect (leading to UB) usage of `mem::initialized` in `linked-hash-map 0.3`, which is a transitive dependency of `pdf_extract`.